# Windows Phone 8.1, avoid to store a frame in the backstack

Tags: navigation, windows-phone-8.1, back-stack

I am using

```
this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(Page2));
```

to navigate, and in the Page2 I look if I can go Back and handle the back button.

The problem is that I am doing a page that I don't want it to be stored in the backstack, I know that I can do

```
this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(Page2));
this.Frame.BackStack.RemoveAt(this.Frame.BackStack.Count - 1);
```

but before remove it the "OnNavigatedTo" is launched and it prepares the Page2 (showing a button to do back).

There is any way to use navigate and don't store in the BackStack this page?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try Executing

```
 this.Frame.BackStack.RemoveAt(this.Frame.BackStack.Count - 1);
```

in the **OnNavigatedTo()** of your first page.
As OnNavigatedTo()is called before your second page loads..